# Can we shorten 'even if' to 'if'?

Tags: word-usage

This sentence is taken from McCarthy's book:

> Melissa was a sent-minded, easy-going, good-tempered, warm-hearted,
> and quick-witted, **if** perhaps a little big-headed, two-faced,
> self-centered, and, stuck up at times.

I assume, **if** there means *even if*. Or is it just the word *if* with different meaning? I couldn't find the definition from Oxford dictionary that matches with this usage, if that so.

Comment: Yes, you're right; see [definition 4 here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if)

Comment: Agree with @AndyBonner, but note that you can't simply replace "even if" with "if" in all sentences.